# Table join: unable to show the data what I want

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

If I have table like this:

```
ID | Title | Topic      | Summary    
1   |   A   | Technology | ...    
2  |   B   | Health     | ...    
3  |   C   | Sport      | ...
```

This is my CI_Model:

```
function show($limit, $offset)
    {
        $this->db->select('document.id, document.title, document.summary, document.id_topic AS topic');
        $this->db->from('document');
        $this->db->join('topic', 'topic.id_topic = document.id_topic');
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'asc');
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

This is my Controller:

```
            $docdata = $this->Trainingmodel->show($this->limit, $offset);
        ...
        $this->table->set_heading('ID', 'Title', 'Topic', 'Summary');
        foreach ($docdata as $doc)
        {
            $this->table->add_row($doc->id, $doc->title, $doc->topic, $doc->summary);                                                                                               
        }
```

Evidently the topic shows it's id, not name.
For example:

```
ID | Title | Topic      | Summary    
1   |   A   | 1 | ...    
2  |   B   | 2  | ...    
3  |   C   | 3  | ...
```

What should I do? I want to show topic's name, not topic's id.

Comment: What is your table structure for `topic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your table structure you posted as comments in the other answers, I think you need `topic.topic` in your `select()` and `topic.id = document.id_topic` in your `join()` -

```
$this->db->select('document.id, document.title, document.summary, topic.topic');
$this->db->from('document');
$this->db->join('topic', 'topic.id = document.id_topic');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('document.id, document.title, document.summary, topic.topic');
$this->db->from('document');
$this->db->join('topic', 'topic.id = document.id_topic');
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have 2 table like this:

*1st table (Table of topic)*

Structure: id (INT (1)), topic (varchar (25))

*2nd table (table of document)*

Structure: id (INT 3), title (varchar (100)), id_topic (INT (1)), summary (TEXT)


When i tried to use your solution, it gaves me a warning:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object**

Comment: @user2338965 You did not tell the structure first. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because of this `document.id_topic`

```
$this->db->select('document.id, document.title, document.summary, document.id_topic AS topic');
```

should it be something like `document.topic` or `document.name_topic` ?

Comment: It doesn't work. I have 2 table like this:
*1st table (Table of topic)*

Structure: id (INT (1)), topic (varchar (25))
*2nd table (table of document)*

Structure: id (INT 3), title (varchar (100)), id_topic (INT (1)), summary (TEXT)

When i tried to use your solution, it gaves me a warning:
**Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object**